# Zend Framework Routing - passing hidden params

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to pass additional params through the URL helper and router - that therefore will not appear in the address bar - but are accessible via the getParam call

My route is below - notice the tagID I want to be passed invisibly though

```
        'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'tag' => array(
                'route' => '/tag/:tag',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'module' => 'default',
                    'controller' => 'tags',
                    'action' => 'profile',
                    'tag'   => '',
                    'tagID' => ''
                )
            )
        )
```

The URL helper specifies the TagID

url(array('tag' => $tag, 'tagID' => $v->id), 'tag', true) ?>

Basically is this possible to then get the address bar to show

localhost.com/tag/php

but the controller to have access to the tag and tagID params?

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as far as I know. There's nowhere to hide any variables because you're dealing with a standard GET request. This is really about the http protocol, not Zend.

There are two ways of moving data/state between urls: GET (i.e. Encoded into the actual URL and POST.

As a POST request isn't appropriate here you're unfortunately stuck with visible URL parameters, or reconstructing the tagID from the tag name on the receiving page.

Comment: Thanks - I thought as much, just wanted clarification on this really, incase there was some black art to do it gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a route for each tag, you can assign defaults for them and you won't need to explicitly define them in the url.

Like this (foreach tag):

```
        'route' => '/tag/php',
        'defaults' => array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'tags',
            'action' => 'profile',
            'tag'   => 'php',
            'tagID' => 'phpID'
        )
```

Comment: A route for each tag? Sounds like a huge performance issue. If I had 10,000 tags then the system would need to parse 10,000 routes on each request to the tag controller. Please tell me if I am missing something here?

Comment: With that amount, it certainly wouldn't be feasible to do it that way. If you intend to have 10,000 tags, you should probably just keep the tags unique, and do a db lookup for the tagID, from the provided tag.

Comment: Hi, tags are unique and I want to pass through the TagID in the request - hence the route requirement - the question really is about whether I can hide the tagID from the address bar and whether Zend can automagically pass it through in the route mechanism. The other way would be for me to do some Apache mod_rewrites - just exploring options here.

Comment: If it is not stored in the URL, where would it be stored then? The application won't just automatically know what tagID belongs to which tag, so you will need to map it somewhere. If it really is the case that you will have ~10k tags, writing them up into an array or something really wouldn't be a good idea, so I would recommend using a database lookup for that.

Comment: I am passing the tagID in the url helper - taken from the database: url(array('tag' => $tag, 'tagID' => $v->id), 'tag', true) - what I dont want is the tagID to form part of the url in the addressbar Ie I want /tag/php not /tag/php/1 - so my question revolves around whether what I want to do is even possible?

Comment: You can make it /tag/php and drop the /1, but you won't be able to retrieve that tagID value from the request then.

Answer (score 0):

In your action use:
`$tagId = $this->_getParam('tagId', 'yourDefaultValue');`

Comment: Hi, I know how to get the values - its the issue that the values arent present. I am unsure whether it is even possible in zend to pass extra params that arent tokenised in the route. ie I probably should use - 'route' => '/tag/:tag/:tagID',